# How to work with relationship properties on a Asp.Net MVC 3 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Could anyone help me figure out what is the standard way to display a lookup property for a model on my view?

Let's say I have the following models:

```
public class ProfileModel()
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel()
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Login { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public ProfileModel Profile { get; set; }
}
```

My UserController have the following actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  return View(new UserModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserModel model)
{
  //Do something
}
```

How should my view look like? I'm sending an empty UserModel. And I would like for the user to select a profile on a select list.

Is it a standard for complex and big applications to use the view bag to send the list with profile options to the select list?

Should I create a custom editor for ProfileModel?

I actually know I have many options. But I would like to find out what is the best solution for larger applications. One of the things I'm having a hard time to figure out is that I need a way to display the select list but still allowing the Model Binder to create an instance of Profile when I'm posting the data so I can save it to the database.

I appreciate any guidance! Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is "partial views."  Have a look here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

Are these entity framework models? If they are then add a forgien key id property so you can easily set the Id based on the value from a dropdown.

Might want to look at MVC Scaffolding http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/. It can auto generate views etc for you and provide drop down lists to select foreign keys. All it does is store foreign key properties in the view bag and makes a select list.